# Laravel Livewire Dynamic Checkboxes Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have dynamic checkbox but how can I validate if use don't select at least one of the choice? Below is my code and if I'm going to remove the $key in wire:model I am able save the data but I can't validate. But if there is a $key on it all checkboxes marked as checked at once if they select at least option.

I want to have a unique ID of checkboxes to validate each question.

```
@foreach ($questions as $key => $question)
    @foreach ($question->choices as $choice)
        <div>
            <input wire:model="checkbox.{{ $key }}" value="{{ $choice->id }}" name="{{ $question->id }}" id="{{ $choice->id }}" type="checkbox">
            <label for="{{ $question->id }}">{{ $choice->id }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edNAb.png)

Comment: You should make the keys unique, it would help if we could see how you pass `$questions` to your view.

Comment: Here $this->questions = Question::with('choices')->where('promo_id', $this->promo_id)->get(); from the mount..

Comment: By the way keys already unique because it's from questions loop this should be same as loop->index.

Comment: you have to show us the properties on your laravel component.